# Rails 4 - Stylesheets from public folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, stylesheet, assets

I have a problem with including `stylesheets and javascript files` from public folder into my project.

I do it in following way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/public/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css' %>
```

Unfortunatelly I've got an error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css")
```

Can u tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the '/public/' path.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css' %>
```

Files under public don't need the `/public/` path. An example are your error pages that can be reached by `localhost:3000/404.html`

Enabling this in production requires you to enable it in your environment file.

In `production.rb`

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```